# Not able to access data from SAP HANA to SQL via SSIS 2012 (Data Tools)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, hana

I have to pull data from SAP HANA to SQL via SSIS (2012).

Steps performed:

1. Created DB Admin Role in SAP HANA for the user
2. Downloaded SAP HANA driver URL: **https://www.progress.com/odbc/sap-hana**
3. Installed 32 bit SAP HANA ODBC driver
4. Created SSIS package with ODBC source and destination

Issue:

1. Able to preview data in ODBC source from SAP HANA
2. But when I run the package it fails saying couldn't able to acquire ODBC connection
3. I have tried running package in 32 bit/64 bit but both fails

Attaching screenshot for the issue:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

Issue was credential was flushing at runtime.

So create dynamic connection using Expression property.

[image]

Comment: Mark your answer as a solution for future askers.